# Don't show trailing zeros in QDoubleSpinBox?

Tags: qt

Normally when I have a double spinbox with for example 4 decimals, when the number is set to 4 it shows it as 4.0000.  What I don't like to have to do when changing the fractional part of the number with the keyboard after clicking on the spinbox is then delete those four zeros to add my own digits, I'd rather it show '4' initially then I could click on the spinbox, type a period then add up to four digits.

Is that possible?

Here is the ui xml currently:

```
      <widget class="QDoubleSpinBox" name="move_dist_spinbox">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="decimals">
        <number>4</number>
       </property>
       <property name="minimum">
        <double>-500.000000000000000</double>
       </property>
       <property name="maximum">
        <double>500.000000000000000</double>
       </property>
       <property name="singleStep">
        <double>1.000000000000000</double>
       </property>
       <property name="value">
        <double>80.000000000000000</double>
       </property>
      </widget>
```

I'm using python and python_qt_binding.

Comment: You could show your code. Read this: [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added the xml qtdesigner spits out.

Comment: I believe editing selects by default all the digits so you can replace everything. It seems like a very particular use case to only change the fractional part. I guess you can work with the focus event to change the string of QLineEdit on the fly (= remove trailing zeros), but the behaviour might be weird for the user.